# SQL query to obtain how many product sold for each day of a month in each product category

Tags: sqlite

Here is the problem: I have a table containing sales numbers (price, date, store). The store is not important but I need a query generate the results like in this example

```
Date          Price
12/01/2012    100   
12/01/2012    150
12/01/2012    270
13/01/2012    50
13/01/2012    150
13/01/2012    230
14/01/2012    330
```

Resulting table should look like this

```
Date             0-100 100-200 200-300  300-400
12/01/2012       0       1       1        0
13/01/2013       1       1       1        1
```

So basically I need a query to automatically identify all the unique dates in the table and after that count the sales in each price range for each day

I apologize if this is banal, I am learning SQL. BTW this is SQLite3 
I guess your answer can be for any SQL falvour but please bear in mind that I will have to use sqlite

Thanks in advance
C

Comment: what have you tried? you need to show some effort in solving your issue, this is not a place where to ask others to do your job.

Comment: Hi guido. I have tried something like these but I could not combine them together. As I indicated I am a beginner, in fact I am network engineer "by trade" and this is not my job.      count (prod.Price) AS "300K", 
  (SELECT count (prod.Price) 
  WHERE prod.Price <400 and prod.Price > 300) AS "400", 
  (SELECT count (prod.Price) 
  WHERE prod.Price <500 and prod.Price > 400) AS "500", 
  (SELECT count (prod.Price) 
  WHERE prod.Price <600 and prod.Price > 500) AS "600", 
WHERE prod.Price <300 
SELECT SoldDate, count(SoldDate) 
FROM prod 
WHERE prod.SoldDate > '07/01/2013' 
group by SoldDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Date,
       SUM(Price BETWEEN   0 AND  99) AS '0-100',
       SUM(Price BETWEEN 100 AND 199) AS '100-200',
       SUM(Price BETWEEN 200 AND 299) AS '200-300',
       SUM(Price BETWEEN 300 AND 399) AS '300-400'
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Date
```

Comment: thanks a lot CL, that did the job, as I expected it was banal but... I stil can't wrap my mind around working with sets. I have some limited experience with Python but that is all...